# Using CASE/IF statement in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table in DB like this:

```
ID  UserId ProductGender
```

Now when a user purchases a product, a entry is made in this table in which there is useID and gender of product. The values of ProductGender can be `Men`, `Women` and `None`

How can i get the count of each user's purchased Men product and Women product.

I have tried `CASE` and `THEN` but cant figure out the right way!

Comment: is the php tag necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select userid, 
       sum(productgender = 'Men') as men_sum,
       sum(productgender = 'Women') as women_sum,
       sum(productgender = 'None') as none_sum,
       count(*) - sum(productgender = 'Men') * 100 / count(*) as men_percentage
from your_table
group by userid
```

Comment: Yes. That is simple math.